# can't see the content after assigned "read only/read write" on /photo folder to a custom group

Tags: synology

My NAS is DS218+/DSM7.1 and put all my photos under /photo folder.

Created a new group, and assigned "read only" on above folder. Also created a new user who belongs to this group.

After the new user logged in, the photo folder CAN be seen, but the content in the folder can't be seen. Also tried the "read/write", also not work. If I change the new user to "administrator", the content will be listed.

But I would like to keep the new group "view only"right. Is there a way to achieve it?